# Python: Count and rearrange numbers with same value in a list

Tags: python

How do I convert a list, for example:

`['2', '5', '2', '5', '5', '3']`

to something like:

`2^2 * 5^3 * 3`?

My idea was, if there was more then one of the same number, to merge them to something like 5^3 (three fives).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [`collections.Counter` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counts = Counter(['2', '5', '2', '5', '5', '3'])
>>> counts
Counter({'5': 3, '2': 2, '3': 1})
>>> ' * '.join(['{}^{}'.format(k, v) for k, v in counts.most_common()])
'5^3 * 2^2 * 3^1'
```

or, a little more complex to drop the `1`:

```
>>> ' * '.join(['{}^{}'.format(k, v) if v > 1 else k for k, v in counts.most_common()])
'5^3 * 2^2 * 3'
```

The `Counter.most_common()` method returns the counts in descending sorted order by count, but you can also just use normal dictionary access to list the number-count pairs in arbitrary order.

Comment: +1. You beat me to it by a few seconds :)

Comment: Yes you are right; I mistook `*` for `+`. +1 anyway..

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> A = ['2', '5', '2', '5', '5', '3']
>>> print(*[('%s^%i' % (i,A.count(i))) for i in set(A)] , sep = ' * ')
5^3 * 2^2 * 3^1
```

It works by getting the count of each unique element in set(A) (which gives you all the numbers) and putting it in a tuple with the element itself. [2,2] -> (set) {2}. Which you iterate over and end up with (2,[2,2].count(2))

Comment: Please explain why this works..

Comment: @YotamOmer It works by getting the *count* of each unique element in `set(A)` (which gives you all the numbers) and putting it in a tuple with the element itself. `[2,2]` -> (set) `{2}`. Which you iterate over and end up with `(2,[2,2].count(2))`.

Comment: Holy exponential computational cost, batman! This'll scan the whole list for every unique number added.

Comment: @MartijnPieters LOL. Use `collections.Counter`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter

dataset = ['2', '5', '2', '5', '5', '3']

factorials = Counter(dataset)

output_parts = []
for base, exponent in factorials.items():
    if exponent == 1:
        output_parts.append(base)
    else:
        output_parts.append("%s^%s" % (base, exponent))

output = ' * '.join(output_parts)
print(output)
```

Gives you:

```
3 * 2^2 * 5^3
```

Comment: I see, I was typing the code and after submitting I saw that you already posted a short answer which covered the usage of `Counter`. I did not delete my answer since mine covered the string output part.